# os.getenv('TOKEN') returns None with TOKEN defined in .env

Tags: python

In the same folder, I have an `.env` file and a `main.py` file.

In `.env` I have set

```
TOKEN = 123456
```

And in `main.py` I have

```py
import os
print(os.getenv('TOKEN'))
```

When I run the Python script, I get `None` in the standard output. What am I doing wrong?

I have looked at all the similar questions but it seems like I'm not missing any steps. I'm using MacOS if that affects anything.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Python doesn't know anything about `.env` files. How are you trying to load values from that file?

Comment: @GinoMempin I think dotenv is the way to go. I was following a discord bot making tutorial that involves saving the API key in an .env variable, which can be found [here](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/create-a-discord-bot-with-python/), and encountered the above issue. Not sure why it worked for the tutorial maker. They used repl.it for the tutorial and I did too, but for some reason mine did not work. Anyways I'm moving ahead with `dotenv`!

Comment: Because putting key-value pairs in a .env file does not automatically export them as environment variables. And Python's .getenv or .environ only reads from environment variables. As [asked by another user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65693810/os-getenvtoken-returns-none-with-token-defined-in-env?noredirect=1#comment116151352_65693810), the tutorial probably does some other steps to load the .env file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to load your .env file beforehand.

You can do it as follow:

```
from dotenv import load_dotenv
load_dotenv()
```

You can find more details in the [python-dotenv documentation](https://pypi.org/project/python-dotenv/)