# python-dotenv is not importing PRIVATE_KEY from .env file

Tags: python, solidity

```
from solcx import compile_standard
import json
from web3 import Web3
import os
from dotenv import load_dotenv



my_address = "0xDFb3e342C0A8F724bfA72e5F2773a12748977f46"
private_key = os.getenv("PRIVATE_KEY")
```

I am learning solidity and when I use python-dotenv to import my PRIVATE_KEY from a .env file,

`export PRIVATE_KEY = 0xd6a5ea3d2c97b1dd03fd1b9c447e36791522135136665f23b0c08c6395f66d7a`

it imports it as none and throws an error.
[this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wsABB.png)
I have given the full script that I wrote above.
I hope someone can help me solve this problem

Comment: You first need to use the load_dotenv() function in order to load your environment variables. You can refer to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65693810/os-getenvtoken-returns-none-with-token-defined-in-env/65694089#65694089

Answer (score 0):

- Make sure `.env` file is in the same directory.
- Calling `load_dotenv` will look for `.env` file and sets the environment variables

  ```
  load_dotenv()
  ```

if `.env` file is not in the same directory you have to pass the path of .env file to `load_dotenv`

```
 load_dotenv(path_of_env)
```